# How to upgrade a custom jQuery UI theme?

Tags: jquery-ui, themes, themeroller

I created 2 custom themes with themeroller for JQuery UI 1.7 with themeroller. Now that I update to jQuery UI 1.8.5, I want to make sure that also my themes are updated. How can I automatically re-generate/update my custom themes with themeroller?

Answer (score 72):

The jQuery UI theme css file includes an edit link in its comments. This link opens Themeroller with the settings of your custom theme.

```
  /*
* jQuery UI CSS Framework
* Copyright (c) 2009 AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt) and GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
* To view and modify this theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?ffDefault=Segoe%20UI,%20Arial,%[...]*/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting your answer to this.  I think you should accept it.

Comment: Yes.  Many many thanks.  You just saved me a huge headache! =)

Comment: What if I changed manually some "margin" or "padding" (Themeroller is quite limited what can be customized)?

Answer (score 3):

To add to fbuchinger's answer, this didn't work for me at first - one of the colours came through invalid, so the page did not display the theme properly and I was unable to download it.

If you have the same problem, check there is nothing highlighted red (error), correct as required and it should be OK.

And yes I know this would be better as a comment, but I don't have the required 50 reputation to comment.