# Easy Way to Change jQuery UI Theme?

Tags: jquery-ui, themes

Is there an easy way to change the theme of the jQuery UI by replacing certain files? It seems like I have to keep downloading the entire jQuery UI every time I want to change the theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build your own theme at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/.
once you build your theme you will have link both in address bar that you can bookmark and
in your css file `jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css` that you download:

`http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Trebuchet+MS,+Tahoma,+Verdana,+Arial,+sans-ser...`

for each modification you can use these link instead of start from beginning.

**EDIT**

by using `totalcommander compare tool` or `winmerge`, you just do syncronize existing jquery ui files and the new jquery ui files, if you build new one

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you need to change is the stylesheet and the images.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3803291/904846), you can find ThemeRoller edit link in your `css` file. This url contains whole theme settings and this is the best way how migrate/upgrade it.