# jQuery UI Accordion Header: ui-helper-reset is not being added

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have just updated my project's jQuery from 1.9.2 to 1.11.2 and everything seems to be working fine except that my accordion is now so large that I cannot see the content. Prior code:

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    fillSpace: true,
    collapsible: true,
    navigation: true
});
```

As autoHeight, fillSpace and navigation are all deprecated I have updated this to...

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: "fill",
    collapsible: true
});
```

Now I have massive margins below each closed accordion tab and the text is huge. A quick search of the resulting code shows that the only thing that is missing is the **ui-helper-reset** class on the h3-element (i.e. **.accordion** has it, all my content divs have it, but all h3-elements do not).

If I add the class by hand the headers look like they did before. Any ideas on how to get the class to be added?

### Update

This is an internal issue. There is an old custom jQueryUI CSS file (1.8.23) that is messing everything up. I looked at jQuery UI accordions CSS that is generated and the **ui-helper-reset** is no longer being added to header. Which works, if you do not have an old custom CSS file in the way.

Comment: icymbi: I just changed the code in jquery-ui.js from `_processPanels:function(){
 this.headers=this.element.find(this.options.header).addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all")` to `_processPanels:function(){
 this.headers=this.element.find(this.options.header).addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, if you get a similar issue is to update your jQuery CSS. I found out how to do that here:
[How to upgrade a custom jQuery UI theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802447/how-to-upgrade-a-custom-jquery-ui-theme)

Answer (score 1):

how about `.addClass()?`

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: "fill",
    collapsible: true
}).find("h3").addClass("ui-helper-reset");
```

Comment: This will make the headers the right size, but, as I am using heightStyle fill, the content will still be sized as if the headers where not reset.

However, your question helped me find the actual answer so thanks for that! :) (see update)

Comment: code is used on a bunch of pages, cant edit every single function call. can i yes. am I going to? no.